# Loop through a spreadsheet and count unique rows in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, unique, rows, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet with check-ins from users (on different stores) made with my application. People can check in more than once on one store. I already have a loop to count all check-ins (see sample below). What I want is a loop to count all unique checkins. How can I do this in jQuery?

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
      if(data.feed.entry[i].gsx$store.$t == storeName) {
        numberOfCheckIns++;
      }
    }
  });
```

Edit: 
Let me specify the question.
This is how my records are like:

```
id | timecheckedin | points | store | user
```

I want to count all unique users checked in at store "foo"

Comment: made the question more specific

Answer (score 0):

I did it myself already. Feel free to comment if there is a more efficient way.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $.each(data.feed.entry, function (index, value) {
    if (value.gsx$store.$t == storeName) {
      if($.inArray(value.gsx$user.$t, uniqueNames) === -1) {
            uniqueNames.push(value.gsx$user.$t);
      }
        numberOfCheckIns++;
      }     
    });
      amountOfUniqueFans = uniqueNames.length;
});
```